# How to stop going to next life cycle hook in vueJs?

Tags: vue.js

My vue page contains Created, mounted, updated, destroyed hooks. I need to add a condition for page rendering. In my case, in the created hook I make a variable  true or false based on a confirm alert and if it true I would like the vue to execute other lifecycle hooks else route to a different page.
Is it possible with vue to do this, if yes, how?

Comment: Place the condition in your desired hook and redirect. None of the subsequent lifecycles will execute, because the current component is destroyed. Check out the [lifecycle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) to understand the hooks order.

Comment: Actually I was using confirm component  [https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-confirm-dialog ] in the created hook. If the condition true inside the confirm component then I go to next hooks otherwise I route to other page, Due to some reason it was not working and before I confirm all the lifecycle hooks are executed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `created` hook if this value is false and you want to redirect to different page you can use [**`location API`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

```js
//...
  created: function () {
// your code
    window.location.replace("https://google.com"); // this will redirect you to another page
  }
//...
```

Comment: Due to use of confirm component from [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-confirm-dialog ] I have this issue. However I have solved by creating a dummy page and routing to it till I confirm the dialogue.